# About HTTP Live Streaming

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I am really tired of this issue. If any one help me in this then it will be appreciated.
My one app is rejected and reason is

> Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live and include a baseline 64 kbps audio-only HTTP Live stream.

I tried much for this and finally i have submitted TSI report for this issue.
but i am not clear what they suggested to do.
need some help from you guys.

What i have done is
1. Download and install HTTP Live Streaming Tool.
2. I've Segmented my video by using this command
**mediafilesegmenter -a -t 10 Desktop/Sample.mp4**
Above command gave us audio segments in **.aac** format.
(Here i use **-a** tag because in TSI reply they said that **include baseline 64 kbps audio only**)

Now they suggested me in TSI report

> For the 64 kbits stream, if you're using transport streams, we recommend you create a simple audio elementary stream, perhaps with a poster frame jpg image.

from this sentence only i come to know is I have to create audio stream from my video that i have already created.
But i don't know whether it is 64kbps or not. So how to check this?? or how to apply 64kbps to my audio stream??
The other thing is they said **perhaps with a poster frame jpg image**. So what should i do for getting poster frame jpg image from my video ?
how to connect this image with my audio stream to get my full video ???
This things are really confusing me.
Please help me out this. If u can give solution by some example commands that i can use, then it would be very helpful to understand me all this confusing things..

Thanks in advance..!!!!

Comment: Can anyone please help me in this..??:(

Answer (score 1):

To check the average bit-rate of an HLS stream, you need to use the mediastreamvalidator tool.

What often happens with the 64kbps stream is that it may not be under this value throughout its entire length.

Run the following command on your suspect 64kbps stream(s) and check the 'Average segment bitrate' value reported

```
mediastreamvalidator --verbose validate <StreamUrl>
```